# Error setting expression 'userBean.password' with value ['', ]

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, getter-setter, mutators

I'm using struts 2 and tomcat together.
The problem I'm facing is: whenever I submit data whether is wrong or not (username and password) it ALLWAYS makes following field error appear:

```
.Error setting expression 'userBean.password' with value ['XXX', ]
.Error setting expression 'userBean.username' with value ['YYY', ]
```

where 'XXX' is the password and 'YYY' is the username.

My action class is:

```
package direstruts.action;

import static com.opensymphony.xwork2.Action.SUCCESS;
import direstruts.model.UserBean;

public class LoginAction extends GenericAction {

    @Override
    public void validate() {
        UserBean uB = getUserBean();
        if(uB.getUsername().isEmpty()) {
            addFieldError("userBean.username", "Por favor Insira o Username de Utilizador");
        }
        if(uB.getPassword().isEmpty()) {
            addFieldError("userBean.password", "Por favor Insira a Password de Utilizador");
        }
    }

    public String getAuthentication() throws Exception {
        if(getUserBean().getAuthentication()) {
            addActionMessage("Log in bem Sucedido!");
            return SUCCESS;
        }
        addActionError("Utilizador e/ou Password errados e/ou Utilizador já está logado");
        return ERROR;
    }

    public String setNewUser() throws Exception {
        if(getUserBean().setNewUser()) {
            addActionMessage("User registado!");
            return SUCCESS;
        }
        addActionError("Utilizador Já Existe! Tente Outro Username!");
        return ERROR;
    }
    public String setQuitUser() throws Exception {
        if(getUserBean().setQuitUser()) {
            addActionMessage("User LoggedOut!");
            return SUCCESS;
        }
        return ERROR;
    }

    public UserBean getUserBean() {
        if(!session.containsKey("userBean"))
            this.setUserBean(new UserBean());
        return (UserBean) session.get("userBean");
    }

    public void setUserBean(UserBean userBean) {
        session.put("userBean", userBean);
    }
}
```

My jsp is:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css"> 
        <title>MeeTO</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <s:form action="loginAction" method="post" >
            <s:label cssClass="login" value="Please fill in the form below in order to Register or Log in:" /> <br>

            <s:label for="userBean.username" value="Username:"/> 
            <s:textfield name="userBean.username" /> <br>

            <s:label for="userBean.password"  value="Password:"/> 
            <s:password name="userBean.password" /> <br>

            <s:submit value="LogIn" action="loginAction" /> <br>
            <s:submit value="Register" action="registerAction" /> <br>
        </s:form>

        <s:fielderror/>
        <s:actionerror/>
        <s:actionmessage/>
    </body>
</
```

My bean is:

```
package direstruts.model;

import cliente.replies.ReplyLogin;
import cliente.replies.ReplyObj;
import cliente.requests.lookup.GetAuthentication;
import cliente.requests.modify.SetNewUser;
import cliente.requests.modify.SetQuitUser;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.rmi.NotBoundException;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.util.Properties;
import servidorRMI.ExecuteCommands;

public class UserBean {
    ExecuteCommands eC;
    private static String ip_RMI = "127.0.0.1";
    private static int serverRMI = 1099;
    private static InputStream in;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private int idUser;

    public UserBean() {
        readProperties();
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public int getIdUser() {
        return this.idUser;
    }

    public void setIdUser(int idUser) {
        this.idUser = idUser;
    }

    public boolean getAuthentication() {
        GetAuthentication gA = new GetAuthentication(getUsername(), getPassword(), 0);
        ReplyLogin rL = null;
        boolean cond = false;
        do{
            try {
                eC = (ExecuteCommands)Naming.lookup("rmi://" + ip_RMI + ":" + serverRMI + "/ServerRMI");
                rL = eC.getAuthentication(gA);
                cond = false;
            } catch (RemoteException ex) {
                System.err.println("Erro no servidor RMI Remote! A tentar restablecer a ligação!");
                cond = true;
            } catch (NotBoundException ex) {
                System.err.println("Erro no servidor RMI NotBound! A tentar restablecer a ligação!");
                cond = true;
            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                System.err.println("Erro no servidor RMI MalformedURL! A tentar restablecer a ligação!");
                cond = true;
            }
        } while(cond);
        setIdUser(rL.getIdUser()); // Faz set ao idUser para poder ser usado nos pedidos subsequentes
        return rL.isHasRegister();
    }

    public boolean setNewUser() {
        SetNewUser sNU = new SetNewUser(getUsername(), getPassword(), 0);
        boolean cond = false;
        ReplyObj rO = null;
        do{
            try {
                eC = (ExecuteCommands)Naming.lookup("rmi://" + ip_RMI + ":" + serverRMI + "/ServerRMI");
                rO = eC.setNewUser(sNU);
                cond = false;
            } catch (RemoteException ex) {
                System.err.println("Erro no servidor RMI Remote! A tentar restablecer a ligação!");
                cond = true;
            } catch (NotBoundException ex) {
                System.err.println("Erro no servidor RMI NotBound! A tentar restablecer a ligação!");
                cond = true;
            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                System.err.println("Erro no servidor RMI MalformedURL! A tentar restablecer a ligação!");
                cond = true;
            }
        } while(cond);
        return rO.getSuccess();
    }

    public boolean setQuitUser() {
        SetQuitUser sQU = new SetQuitUser(idUser, 0);
        boolean cond = false;
        ReplyObj rO = null;
        do{
            try {
                eC = (ExecuteCommands)Naming.lookup("rmi://" + ip_RMI + ":" + serverRMI + "/ServerRMI");
                rO = eC.setQuitUser(sQU);
                cond = false;
            } catch (RemoteException ex) {
                System.err.println("Erro no servidor RMI Remote! A tentar restablecer a ligação!");
                cond = true;
            } catch (NotBoundException ex) {
                System.err.println("Erro no servidor RMI NotBound! A tentar restablecer a ligação!");
                cond = true;
            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                System.err.println("Erro no servidor RMI MalformedURL! A tentar restablecer a ligação!");
                cond = true;
            }
        } while(cond);
        return rO.getSuccess();
    }

    static public void readProperties() {
        try {
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            in = UserBean.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("app.properties");
            properties.load(in);
            ip_RMI = properties.getProperty("serverRMI.address");
            serverRMI = Integer.parseInt (properties.getProperty("serverRMI.port"));
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Erro a ler o ficheiro .properties!");
        } finally {
            if(in != null) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch(IOException e) {System.out.println("Erro a fechar!"); }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is Tomcat Log:

```
19-Nov-2014 14:21:04.618 WARNING [http-apr-8080-exec-109] com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger.warn Parameter [action:loginAction] is on the excludeParams list of patterns!
19-Nov-2014 14:21:05.086 SEVERE [http-apr-8080-exec-109] null.null Notificação para o Desenvolvedor (altere o paramêtro struts.devMode para false para desabilitar esta mensagem):
Unexpected Exception caught setting 'userBean.password' on 'class direstruts.action.LoginAction: Error setting expression 'userBean.password' with value ['YYY', ]
19-Nov-2014 14:21:05.101 SEVERE [http-apr-8080-exec-109] null.null Notificação para o Desenvolvedor (altere o paramêtro struts.devMode para false para desabilitar esta mensagem):
Unexpected Exception caught setting 'userBean.username' on 'class direstruts.action.LoginAction: Error setting expression 'userBean.username' with value ['XXX', ]
19-Nov-2014 14:21:05.210 WARNING [http-apr-8080-exec-109] com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger.warn Caught an exception while evaluating expression 'userBean.username' against value stack
 Caught an Ognl exception while getting property userBean - Class: ognl.OgnlRuntime
File: OgnlRuntime.java
Method: getMethodValue
Line: 1456 - ognl/OgnlRuntime.java:1456:-1
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.CompoundRootAccessor.getProperty(CompoundRootAccessor.java:143)
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.getProperty(OgnlRuntime.java:2317)
    at ognl.ASTProperty.getValueBody(ASTProperty.java:114)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258)
    at ognl.ASTChain.getValueBody(ASTChain.java:141)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258)
    at ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:494)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.getValue(OgnlUtil.java:255)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.getValue(OgnlValueStack.java:358)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.tryFindValue(OgnlValueStack.java:347)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.tryFindValueWhenExpressionIsNotNull(OgnlValueStack.java:322)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.findValue(OgnlValueStack.java:308)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.findValue(OgnlValueStack.java:366)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.TextParseUtil$1.evaluate(TextParseUtil.java:157)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.OgnlTextParser.evaluate(OgnlTextParser.java:49)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.TextParseUtil.translateVariables(TextParseUtil.java:167)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.TextParseUtil.translateVariables(TextParseUtil.java:112)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.TextParseUtil.translateVariables(TextParseUtil.java:85)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.Component.findValue(Component.java:353)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.UIBean.evaluateParams(UIBean.java:813)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.UIBean.end(UIBean.java:544)
    at org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ComponentTagSupport.doEndTag(ComponentTagSupport.java:42)
    at org.apache.jsp.loginPage_jsp._jspx_meth_s_005ftextfield_005f0(loginPage_jsp.java:273)
    at org.apache.jsp.loginPage_jsp._jspx_meth_s_005fform_005f0(loginPage_jsp.java:182)
    at org.apache.jsp.loginPage_jsp._jspService(loginPage_jsp.java:114)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:721)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:466)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:391)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletDispatcherResult.doExecute(ServletDispatcherResult.java:164)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:186)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:371)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:275)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:562)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1081)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:277)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2403)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2392)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: ognl.OgnlException: userBean [java.lang.NullPointerException]
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.getMethodValue(OgnlRuntime.java:1456)
    at ognl.ObjectPropertyAccessor.getPossibleProperty(ObjectPropertyAccessor.java:60)
    at ognl.ObjectPropertyAccessor.getProperty(ObjectPropertyAccessor.java:147)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.ObjectAccessor.getProperty(ObjectAccessor.java:17)
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.getProperty(OgnlRuntime.java:2317)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.CompoundRootAccessor.getProperty(CompoundRootAccessor.java:138)
    ... 68 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:434)
    at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:353)
    at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:341)
    at direstruts.model.UserBean.readProperties(UserBean.java:128)
    at direstruts.model.UserBean.<init>(UserBean.java:27)
    at direstruts.action.LoginAction.getUserBean(LoginAction.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.invokeMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:891)
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.getMethodValue(OgnlRuntime.java:1454)
    ... 73 more

19-Nov-2014 14:21:05.288 WARNING [http-apr-8080-exec-109] com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger.warn NOTE: Previous warning message was issued due to devMode set to true.
19-Nov-2014 14:21:05.429 WARNING [http-apr-8080-exec-109] com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger.warn Caught an exception while evaluating expression 'userBean.password' against value stack
 Caught an Ognl exception while getting property userBean - Class: ognl.OgnlRuntime
File: OgnlRuntime.java
Method: getMethodValue
Line: 1456 - ognl/OgnlRuntime.java:1456:-1
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.CompoundRootAccessor.getProperty(CompoundRootAccessor.java:143)
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.getProperty(OgnlRuntime.java:2317)
    at ognl.ASTProperty.getValueBody(ASTProperty.java:114)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258)
    at ognl.ASTChain.getValueBody(ASTChain.java:141)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258)
    at ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:494)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.getValue(OgnlUtil.java:255)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.getValue(OgnlValueStack.java:358)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.tryFindValue(OgnlValueStack.java:347)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.tryFindValueWhenExpressionIsNotNull(OgnlValueStack.java:322)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.findValue(OgnlValueStack.java:308)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.findValue(OgnlValueStack.java:366)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.TextParseUtil$1.evaluate(TextParseUtil.java:157)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.OgnlTextParser.evaluate(OgnlTextParser.java:49)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.TextParseUtil.translateVariables(TextParseUtil.java:167)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.TextParseUtil.translateVariables(TextParseUtil.java:112)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.TextParseUtil.translateVariables(TextParseUtil.java:85)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.Component.findValue(Component.java:353)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.UIBean.evaluateParams(UIBean.java:813)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.UIBean.end(UIBean.java:544)
    at org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ComponentTagSupport.doEndTag(ComponentTagSupport.java:42)
    at org.apache.jsp.loginPage_jsp._jspx_meth_s_005fpassword_005f0(loginPage_jsp.java:313)
    at org.apache.jsp.loginPage_jsp._jspx_meth_s_005fform_005f0(loginPage_jsp.java:191)
    at org.apache.jsp.loginPage_jsp._jspService(loginPage_jsp.java:114)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:721)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:466)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:391)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletDispatcherResult.doExecute(ServletDispatcherResult.java:164)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:186)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:371)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:275)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:562)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1081)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:277)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2403)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2392)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: ognl.OgnlException: userBean [java.lang.NullPointerException]
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.getMethodValue(OgnlRuntime.java:1456)
    at ognl.ObjectPropertyAccessor.getPossibleProperty(ObjectPropertyAccessor.java:60)
    at ognl.ObjectPropertyAccessor.getProperty(ObjectPropertyAccessor.java:147)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.ObjectAccessor.getProperty(ObjectAccessor.java:17)
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.getProperty(OgnlRuntime.java:2317)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.CompoundRootAccessor.getProperty(CompoundRootAccessor.java:138)
    ... 68 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:434)
    at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:353)
    at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:341)
    at direstruts.model.UserBean.readProperties(UserBean.java:128)
    at direstruts.model.UserBean.<init>(UserBean.java:27)
    at direstruts.action.LoginAction.getUserBean(LoginAction.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.invokeMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:891)
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.getMethodValue(OgnlRuntime.java:1454)
    ... 73 more

19-Nov-2014 14:21:05.507 WARNING [http-apr-8080-exec-109] com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger.warn NOTE: Previous warning message was issued due to devMode set to true.
```

[EDIT]
I forgot to mention I have an action in which all other actions extend. 
Here it is:

```
package direstruts.action;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.SessionAware;

public class GenericAction extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware{
    protected static final long serialVersionUID = 4L;
    protected Map<String, Object> session;

    @Override
    public void setSession(Map<String, Object> session) {
        this.session = session;
    } 
}
```

To preserve action memory, the GenericAction implements SessionAware. Is that ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As reported in [Parameters Interceptor documentation](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/parameters-interceptor.html) (and also [explained in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21021131/1654265)), the exception:

> .Error setting expression 'userBean.password' with value ['XXX', ]

means you are missin a Setter.

JavaBeans convention establishes that you should have a property, with a getter and a setter with the same name, and Struts2 works following those principles, performing introspection through reflection to outline your Action's objects.

What do you have in your code instead ?

```java
public UserBean getUserBean() {
    if(!session.containsKey("userBean"))
        this.setUserBean(new UserBean());
    return (UserBean) session.get("userBean");
}

public void setUserBean(UserBean userBean) {
    session.put("userBean", userBean);
}
```

A little un-standard, uh !

The property `private UserBean userBean;` does not even exists, and getters and setters are doing strange session things (while they should not even have any business).

Change it to

```java
private UserBean userBean;

public UserBean getUserBean() {
    return userBean; 
}

public void setUserBean(UserBean userBean) {
    this.userBean = userBean; 
}
```

And it will work.

Then IF needed, find another way to deal with the session and your object (like `prepare()` method, or even `execute()`).

Comment: That doesn't change anything. You need a private member UserBean, with standard getter/setter. Do not perform operations with session in getters/setters, but in action methods (or in prepare method, carefully)

Comment: Andrea Ligios I've figured out my problem. I've done a Clean and Build in Netbeans and it erased my app.properties file from the classes dir. Sorry for the waste of your time. In the future I'll try to pay more attention to details.

Comment: Good. You should the same fix the getter/setter stuff, it's not a good way to go, imho. You should use getter/setter with a private variable, then only when the user succesfully authenticates, saving his credentials in session. Which is the purpose of saving them every time ? Avoid the property ?