# AJAX validation fails for all form data

Tags: ajax, jsp, struts2, struts2-jquery, struts-validation

I am using ajax jquery validation.

https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/Validation

In my struts.xml, i have

```
<action name="createChannel" class="channel.ChannelAction" method="createChannel">
<interceptor-ref name="jsonValidationWorkflowStack"/>
<result  name="success">createSuccess.jsp</result>
<result  name="input">createChannel.jsp</result>
</action>
```

In JSP page i have:

```
<s:form method="get" action="createChannel" >
<s:textfield name="channelName" label="Channel Name" />
<s:textfield name="channelBand" label="Channel Band"/>
<s:textfield name="vcFrequency" label="Video Carrier Frequency"/>
<s:textfield name="acFrequency" label="Audio Carrier Frequency"/>
<s:select name="chargeType" label="Charge Type" list="{'PrePaid','PostPaid'}"/>
<s:select name="transmissionType" label="Transmission Type" list="{'HD','Standard'}"/>
<s:textfield name="channelCharge" label="Channel Charge"/>
<sj:submit value="Submit" button="true" validate="true" targets="result"  />
</s:form>
<div id="result">Result:</div>
```

I have model class Channel with annotation validations as:

```
public class Channel {
    private int channelId;
    private String channelName;
    private String channelBand;
    private double vcFrequency;
    private double acFrequency;
    private String chargeType; //PrePaid or PostPaid
    private String transmissionType; //HD or Standard
    private double channelCharge;

    private Set<ChannelPackage> channelPackage;

    public Channel(){
        channelPackage=new HashSet<>();
    }

    public int getChannelId() {
        return channelId;
    }

    public void setChannelId(int channelId) {
        this.channelId = channelId;
    }

    @RequiredStringValidator(trim=true,type=ValidatorType.FIELD,message="Please enter valid channel name")
    public String getChannelName() {
        return channelName;
    }

    public void setChannelName(String channelName) {
        this.channelName = channelName;
    }
    @RequiredStringValidator(trim=true,type=ValidatorType.FIELD,message="Please enter valid channel band")
    public String getChannelBand() {
        return channelBand;
    }

    public void setChannelBand(String channelBand) {
        this.channelBand = channelBand;
    }
    @DoubleRangeFieldValidator(type = ValidatorType.SIMPLE,fieldName = "vcFrequency",minInclusive = "40",maxInclusive = "225",message = "The scale must be between ${minInclusive} and ${maxInclusive} (exclusive)")
    public double getVcFrequency() {
        return vcFrequency;
    }

    public void setVcFrequency(double vcFrequency) {
        this.vcFrequency = vcFrequency;
    }
    @DoubleRangeFieldValidator(type = ValidatorType.SIMPLE,fieldName = "acFrequency",minInclusive = "45",maxInclusive = "230",message = "The scale must be between ${minInclusive} and ${maxInclusive} (exclusive)")
    public double getAcFrequency() {
        return acFrequency;
    }

    public void setAcFrequency(double acFrequency) {
        this.acFrequency = acFrequency;
    }

    public String getChargeType() {
        return chargeType;
    }

    public void setChargeType(String chargeType) {
        this.chargeType = chargeType;
    }


    public String getTransmissionType() {
        return transmissionType;
    }

    public void setTransmissionType(String transmissionType) {
        this.transmissionType = transmissionType;
    }
    @DoubleRangeFieldValidator(type = ValidatorType.SIMPLE,fieldName = "channelCharge",minExclusive = "20.5",maxExclusive = "78.5",message = "The scale must be between ${minExclusive} and ${maxExclusive} (exclusive)")
    public double getChannelCharge() {
        return channelCharge;
    }

    public void setChannelCharge(double channelCharge) {
        this.channelCharge = channelCharge;
    }


    public Set<ChannelPackage> getChannelPackage() {
        return channelPackage;
    }

    public void setChannelPackage(Set<ChannelPackage> channelPackage) {
        this.channelPackage = channelPackage;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return channelId+": "+channelName;
    }

}
```

My action class implements the Model Driven Interface. My Problem is:

- Even if I submit the form with correct data, my form shows error
  messages.
- Along with the error messages, The input result returned is
  shown in the result div. Which means I have two forms on jsp page
  after clicking submit button.
- If i remove the jsonValidationWorkflowStack
  interceptors from struts.xml My form is getting submitted twice.

Here is a screenshot after submission:

Please help me get this right.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So many questions in a single one... BTW, here we go:

> **1. Even if I submit the form with correct data, my form shows error messages.**

This is due to the Interceptor Stack you are using:

```xml
<interceptor-ref name="jsonValidationWorkflowStack"/>
```

that is defined as

```xml
<interceptor-stack name="jsonValidationWorkflowStack">
    <interceptor-ref name="basicStack"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="validation">
        <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="jsonValidation"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="workflow"/>
</interceptor-stack>
```

and basicStack is

```xml
<interceptor-stack name="basicStack">
    <interceptor-ref name="exception"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="servletConfig"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="prepare"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="checkbox"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="params"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="conversionError"/>
</interceptor-stack>
```

As you can see, no `ModelDriven Interceptor` is involved here. If you want to keep using ModelDriven, you need to:

- add `ModelDriven Interceptor`, and
- ensure it runs before the `Validation Interceptor`, otherwise the parameters you are sending will not be (yet) set on the model when the validation will be performed.
  [Read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21021131/1654265) to understand exactly what I mean.

This should be enough:

```xml
<action name="createChannel" class="channel.ChannelAction" method="createChannel">
    <interceptor-ref name="modelDriven"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="jsonValidationWorkflowStack"/>
    <result  name="success">createSuccess.jsp</result>
    <result  name="input">createChannel.jsp</result>
</action>
```

> **2. Along with the error messages, The input result returned is shown in the result div. Which means I have two forms on jsp page after clicking submit button.**

This is obvious, your design is like that, how is it supposed to change automagically in case of `INPUT` ? You need to rethink your design. For example, you can target the form you are in, something like:

```xml
<div id="result">
    <s:form method="get" action="createChannel" >
        <s:textfield name="channelName" label="Channel Name" />
        <s:textfield name="channelBand" label="Channel Band"/>
        <s:textfield name="vcFrequency" label="Video Carrier Frequency"/>
        <s:textfield name="acFrequency" label="Audio Carrier Frequency"/>
        <s:select name="chargeType" label="Charge Type" list="{'PrePaid','PostPaid'}"/>
        <s:select name="transmissionType" label="Transmission Type" list="{'HD','Standard'}"/>
        <s:textfield name="channelCharge" label="Channel Charge"/>
        <sj:submit value="Submit" button="true" validate="true" targets="result"  />
    </s:form>
</div>
```

Then both in case of `INPUT` and `SUCCESS`, you return a message, the form and the fields repopulated. It would be better to create a JSP snippet to be used in the original page too with `<s:include/>`, to follow DRY.

Comment: Yes I did. Thanks a Lot...It worked!! I included the modelDriven interceptor