# How to get ActionForm in Struts 2?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, struts2, model-driven, actionform

I am migrating an Struts 1 app to Struts2 and trying to minimize the code changes required.

I need to know how to access the `ActionForm` in a Struts2 `Action` class. Below is my current code and I am getting NPE when trying to access `ActionForm`.

```
Public class DeptBuildingNewAction extends ActionSupport 
implements ServletRequestAware, ServletResponseAware,  ModelDriven<DeptBuidingFormBean> {

private HttpServletRequest request;
private HttpServletResponse response;
private DeptBuidingFormBean form;

public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
    this.request = httpServletRequest;
}

public void setServletResponse(HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) {
    log.debug("Inside setServletResponse");
    this.response = httpServletResponse;
}

public DeptBuidingFormBean getModel() {
    log.debug("Inside getForm");
    return form;
}

public void setModel(DeptBuidingFormBean form) {
    log.debug("Inside setForm");
    this.form = form;
}
```

What is the best way to get the `ActionForm` over here?

Comment: Which line you getting null pointer exception?

Comment: I'd recommend not calling it an `ActionForm` since that has specific meaning. It's the model.

Answer (score 1):

The form (model in Struts2) should be initialized to prevent NPE.

```
private DeptBuidingFormBean form = new DeptBuidingFormBean();
```

The `ModelDriven` action allows to access a model on the view layer and in action directly from the `valueStack`, i.e. without `model` or `form` prefix.

The [`modelDriven` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/model-driven-interceptor.html) should be on the interceptors stack of the action. The default stack contains this interceptor.

**From the docs:**

> Note: The `ModelDrivenInterceptor` will only push the model into the stack when the model is **not `null`**, else it will be ignored.

In the action class you have a field that you can use inside.

Comment: i don't thing so, if it is then why ModelDriven required. in your code it will create new form instead of populated data from request.

Comment: I guess the problem with this approach is that I will always end up getting a new empty ActionForm.

Comment: @user2482616 @RaviGupta To populate data a `params` interceptor is required, and it won't do it if the model is not on `top` of the value stack. Without model driven the action bean is on top (optional). Then binding input fields required to use prefix in name to access bean's properties.

Comment: @Andrea Ligios i will check. Well thanks for your explanation.

Comment: RomanC already explained this in the second revision of his answer :) BTW to better understand how ModelDriven works, taking a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21021131/1654265) might help.

Comment: @AndreaLigios What do you mean by *bypassing the instantiation operation*. Without instantiation and initialization it will not work, I don't think OP is able to convert a whole model to the action property.

Comment: @AndreaLigios If you only *guess* means that you are not sure about it. You may ask a question to clarify details. Or ask OP to clarify which way he/she is getting a form instantiated.

Comment: Thinking about it, you're right, it's always needed, I've removed the misleading comments

Comment: @RaviGupta There's no `ActionForm` in Struts2, the model driven approach have been used to provide this feature using interceptors, but the way it's implemented doesn't work in some cases where the model driven is used. Also you can develop without model driven, so it makes this concept ambiguous.